# Good Directory Layout for .NET Projects with libraries used across applications and using Mercurial

Tags: visual-studio, mercurial

I've been using Mercurial for a bunch of standalone projects.   But now I'm looking at converting a subversion repository to Mercurial thats a lot more busy / complicated.

Given about 40 Library projects and about 20 Applications ( various web / console / wpf, etc) or so.    Various apps make use of various Libs.  All of this is structured under 1 trunk in subversion.  So there's a directory where all the libs live, and a directory where all the apps live.    Very easy to find and reference the libs when creating a new Visual Studio Projects.

simplified....

```
--trunk-|-- libs
        |-- apps
```

Now moving to mercurial, this is less ideal,  it seems the way to handle this is with 1 repository for each app? and sub repositories per each lib you want to use?

```
--app repository-|-- libs
                 |-- app
```

Is this right?

If so,  when starting a new application in visual studio and you want to add various libs,  whats the best/most efficient way to go about it?

I'm getting the feeling the initial setup is a bit painful?  As opposed to the subversion layout where effectively you don't really have to do anything other than reference the library in your visual studio project.

So, hence this question, wanting to know a good directory structure, and how to quickly setup a new project using this structure.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, and this is going to be based on my own opinion and experience in working with larger, distinct applications, but with dependencies, you want to have a repository per distinct, unrelated project, and keep related, possibly dependent projects within the same repo.  I'm not a big fan of Subrepositories, but that might just be to lack of exposure.

The reason for this is that you should want to version related projects together as changing one may affect the other.  In reality, anything that can be pulled into a single solution and have project references, you definitely want to keep together.

Now, there are some exceptions where you may have a library project that you can't necessarily have as part of a solution, but is a reference for a set of projects.  This is where I'd keep a lib folder versioned along side the rest of my applications in the same repo, but the lib folder holds pre-build assemblies.  It can also hold 3rd party vendor assemblies as well.  This is also important to be versioned along with the project that uses them as you can treat a library update for the main project as a minor release.

For other projects that are truly independent, create another repository for it, as it will have its own version life and you do not want changes to it to affect the graph of changes for your other, completely unrelated projects.

Example layout with several related projects and lib folder:

```
[-] Big Product Repo
 --[-] Big Product 1
 ----[+] Dal
 ----[+] Services
 ----[-] Web
 ------[+] Controllers
 ------[+] Models
 ------[+] Views
 --[+] Big Product 2
 --[-] lib
 ----[+] iTextSharp
 ----[+] nHibernate
```

Example layout with another unrelated project in it (for sake of argument, a Windows services project):

```
[-] Small Product Repo
--[-] Windows Services
----[+] Emailer
----[+] Task Runner
```

In reality, though, your folder structure isn't as important as making sure projects that are being treated as one logical unit (a product) are kept together to ensure control over what is built and released.  That is my definition of what a repository should contain and what I use to think about how to split things up if there's more than one versionable product.